# Preview resolution doesn't match codec resolution

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to stream video between devices. I want to support as old devices as possible. So I started with `MediaRecorder` class on Gingerbread (API 10), but it had issues. So now, I'm moving to Jelly Bean (API 16) and `MediaCodec`.

I'm feeding data to codec in Camera's `PreviewCallback`. I have to use the same resolution for preview, and for codec. But on some of our testing devices, there is no intersection between preview resolutions and codecs and their resolutions.

So, how to capture video on those devices? I know there is  `createInputSurface` in `MediaCodec`, but it needs API 18, and I'll have to cut away [over 35 %](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) of devices, which is inacceptable.

So how to solve it?

Code for finding best possible resolution:

```
CamcorderProfile bestProfile() {
    final int[] profiles;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        profiles = new int[]{CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2160P, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QCIF, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW};
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        profiles = new int[]{CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QCIF, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW};
    } else {
        profiles = new int[]{CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW};
    }
    for (final int p : profiles) {
        try {
            final CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(p);
            String encoder = EncoderDebugger.debug(this, profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight).getEncoderName();
            Log.d(String.valueOf(profile.videoFrameWidth + "*" + profile.videoFrameHeight), encoder);
            return profile;
        } catch (final RuntimeException re) {
            Log.e("Profile", re.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

[EncoderDebugger](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/blob/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming/hw/EncoderDebugger.java)

Btw, `QUALITY_CIF` (352×288) is what works on most devices.